# How can I make a tensorflow based Text-generating AI?

Tags: python, tensorflow, artificial-intelligence, chatbot, text-generation

I'm working on a 'AI chatbot' that relates inputs from user to a json file, to return an 'answer', also pre-defined. But the question is that I want to add text-generating function, and I don't know how to do so(in python).I tried before but didn't work with arm architecture.

Can you help me? Thanks in advance.

Here's the code:
'training.py'

```
import random
import json
import pickle
import numpy as np
import tensorflow as tf

import nltk
from nltk.stem import WordNetLemmatizer

lemmatizer = WordNetLemmatizer()

intents = json.loads(open('intents.json').read())

words = []
classes = []
documents = []
ignoreLetters = ['?', '!', '.', ',']

for intent in intents['intents']:
    for pattern in intent['patterns']:
        wordList = nltk.word_tokenize(pattern)
        words.extend(wordList)
        documents.append((wordList, intent['tag']))
        if intent['tag'] not in classes:
            classes.append(intent['tag'])

words = [lemmatizer.lemmatize(word) for word in words if word not in ignoreLetters]
words = sorted(set(words))

classes = sorted(set(classes))

pickle.dump(words, open('words.pkl', 'wb'))
pickle.dump(classes, open('classes.pkl', 'wb'))

training = []
outputEmpty = [0] * len(classes)

for document in documents:
    bag = []
    wordPatterns = document[0]
    wordPatterns = [lemmatizer.lemmatize(word.lower()) for word in wordPatterns]
    for word in words:
        bag.append(1) if word in wordPatterns else bag.append(0)

    outputRow = list(outputEmpty)
    outputRow[classes.index(document[1])] = 1
    training.append(bag + outputRow)

random.shuffle(training)
training = np.array(training)

trainX = training[:, :len(words)]
trainY = training[:, len(words):]

model = tf.keras.Sequential()
model.add(tf.keras.layers.Dense(256, input_shape=(len(trainX[0]),), activation = 'relu'))
model.add(tf.keras.layers.Dropout(0.5))
model.add(tf.keras.layers.Dense(128, activation = 'relu'))
model.add(tf.keras.layers.Dropout(0.5))
model.add(tf.keras.layers.Dense(len(trainY[0]), activation='softmax'))

sgd = tf.keras.optimizers.SGD(learning_rate=0.01, momentum=0.9, nesterov=True)
model.compile(loss='categorical_crossentropy', optimizer=sgd, metrics=['accuracy'])

hist = model.fit(trainX, trainY, epochs=2000, batch_size=5, verbose=1)
model.save('chatbotmodel.h5', hist)
print('Done')
```

chatbot.py:

```
import random
import json
import pickle
import numpy as np
import time
import pyjokes


import nltk
from nltk.stem import WordNetLemmatizer

from tensorflow.keras.models import load_model

lemmatizer = WordNetLemmatizer()
intents = json.loads(open('intents.json').read())

words = pickle.load(open('words.pkl', 'rb'))
classes = pickle.load(open('classes.pkl', 'rb'))
model = load_model('chatbotmodel.h5')

def clean_up_sentence(sentence):
    sentence_words = nltk.word_tokenize(sentence)
    sentence_words = [lemmatizer.lemmatize(word) for word in sentence_words]
    return sentence_words   


def bag_of_words(sentence):
    sentence_words = clean_up_sentence(sentence)
    bag = [0] *len(words)
    for w in sentence_words:
        for i, word in enumerate(words):
            if word == w:
                bag[i] = 1
    return np.array(bag)

def predict_class(sentence):
    bow = bag_of_words(sentence)
    res = model.predict(np.array([bow]))[0]
    ERROR_TRESHOLD = 0.15
    results = [[i, r] for i, r in enumerate(res) if r > ERROR_TRESHOLD]
    
    results.sort(key=lambda x: x[1], reverse=True)
    return_list = []
    for r in results:
        return_list.append({'intent': classes[r[0]], 'probability': str(r[1])})
    return return_list
    
def get_response(intents_list, intents_json):
    tag = intents_list[0]['intent']
    list_of_intents = intents_json['intents']
    for i in list_of_intents:
        if i['tag'] == tag:
            result = random.choice(i['responses'])
            break
    return result



def analyze_result():
    
    if res[0] == '/':
        if res == '/HOUR':
        
            print(time.asctime())
        
        elif res == '/JOKE':
        
            print("Of course! Here's one for you! :")
            print(pyjokes.get_joke(language="en",category="all"))
        
        elif res == '/REPEAT':
        
            res = old_res
            print(res)

    else:
        old_res = res
        print(res)


print('Say hi to Chat-RPI!')

while True:
    message = input("")
    ints = predict_class(message)
    res = get_response(ints, intents)
    analyze_result()
```

intents.json:

```
{
  "intents": [
    {
      "tag": "greetings",
      "patterns": [
        "hello",
        "hey",
        "hi",
        "good day",
        "Greetings",
        "what's up?",
        "how is it going?"
      ],
      "responses": [
        "Hello!",
        "Hey!",
        "What can I do for you?",
        "Hey dude"
      ]
    },
    {
      "tag": "goodbye",
      "patterns": [
        "cya",
        "See you later",
        "Goodbye",
        "I am leaving",
        "Have a good day",
        "bye",
        "see ya"
      ],
      "responses": [
        "Oh, okay!",
        "Bye my dude!",
        "Beep Boop Boop Beep?",
        "see ya",
        "Goodbye!",
        "Sad to see you go :/"
      ]
    },
    {
      "tag": "age",
      "patterns": [
        "How old are you?",
        "Your age?",
        "What's your age",
        "age?",
        "How many years do you have?",
        "Are you inmortal?",
        "age"
      ],
      "responses": [
        "I don't know!",
        "!, It's a secret!"
      ]
    },
    {
      "tag": "name",
      "patterns": [
        "What is your name?",
        "What's your name",
        "what is your name?",
        "name",
        "name?",
        "How are you called",
        "Which is your name?",
        "Who are you?",
        "Who's there?"
      ],
      "responses": [
        "My name is Chat-RPI!",
        "Really? I'm Chat-RPI",
        "Chat-RPI",
        "My friends call me Chat-RPI"
      ]
    },
    {
      "tag": "like_anime",
      "patterns": [
        "do you like anime?",
        "Do you like manga",
        "manga is nice",
        "do you love anime ",
        "Did you watch hetalia?",
        "manga?",
        "anime?"
      ],
      "responses": [
        "Yes!",
        "Of course!",
        "Umm... Yes, except furries",
        "Hell Yes!"
      ]
    },
    {
      "tag": "bestanime",
      "patterns": [
        "What manga/anime is the best?",
        "Which manga do you prefer?",
        "What manga is your favourite?",
        "What anime do you like?",
        "Which is your favourite manga?",
        "your favourite manga?",
        "your favourite anime?"
      ],
      "responses": [
        "Hetalia!",
        "I love history, so I love hetalia!",
        "Hetalia, but I prefer the manga",
        "It's a secret, but I also like Kimetsu No Yaiba!"
      ]
    },
    {
      "tag": "hour",
      "patterns": [
        "What hour it is?",
        "What's the hour??",
        "What hour is right now?",
        "What hour is?",
        "The hour?",
        "In what moment of the day are we?",
        "At which hour we are?"
      ],
      "responses": [
        "/HOUR"
      ]
    },
    {
      "tag": "joke",
      "patterns": [
        "Tell me a joke",
        "Can you tell me a joke?",
        "Tell a joke",
        "Say a joke, please.",
        "Do you know any joke?",
        "I want a joke",
        "Any jokes?",
        "Do you have another more?",
        "Tell another"
      ],
      "responses": [
        "/JOKE"
      ]
    },
    {
      "tag": "repeat_action",
      "patterns": [
        "Try again",
        "Regenerate",
        "Another time",
        "Repeat",
        "Can you do it another time?",
        "Restart",
        "Again"
      ],
      "responses": [
        "/REPEAT"
      ]
    }
  ]
}
```

As you can see, it's pretty simple, but it manages to work on a raspberry pi.

I tried to use a library called transformer/s that used a community-made version of chat-gpt's 2, but didn't worked on arm.

:D

Comment: What is the specificity you mean by "text generation function"?

Comment: I mean that when the user prompts 'Generate a text about... Bananas', eliminates from the string 'Generate a text about...' and passes that to a function that generates text about'bananas'

Comment: "I expect to get a solution to my problem." ... my experience with SO tells me that is exactly NOT how to ask for help here. Too bad, because there are many solutions.